# In Fatal Attraction what did Alex want Dan to do?

Tags: fatal-attraction

At the beginning of the movie, Alex could have had any man in the room. She choose the wimpy Dan even though she knew he was married. She then sexually aggressively seduced him.

After then Dan wants to go back to his wife and she becomes clingy. Did she now expect Dan to leave his wife? As I see it, the woman who is given a man’s name, doing business like a man, mating like a man. I would have expected her to act like a man and treat this as a one night stand.  To me she become suddenly clingy and suddenly falls for this uninteresting partner. That seems very uncharacteristic.

What was Alex's goal when she tried and seduced Dan?

Comment: Your question is whether Alex expected Dan to leave his wife for her, but your main point of confusion seems to be why Alex was attracted to Dan in the first place.

Comment: What in the world is this supposed to mean: “the woman who is given a man’s name, doing business like a man, mating like a man”??

Comment: It seems very odd to characterize Michael Douglass as wimpy, he was the king of erotic thrillers and wall street established him as the complete opposite of a wimp in the same year as fatal attraction. Perhaps there is some cultural misunderstanding, but Dan was a very desirable partner for Alex.

Comment: @ToddWilcox while I'm not a fan of gender stereotypes, and I do agree that this is worded a little funny, its clear the OP is making a parallel between Alex typically behaving like a man whose been having an affair with a women, up until a point. It is often depicted that men who engage in this behavior are fine with things like one night stands, where Alex clearly isn't. So the question for the OP is about why Alex engaged in this perceived to be "male" behavior, if she couldn't handle typical results?

Comment: @sparkytx The new re-imaged Fatal Attraction TV series definitely attempts to unpack things the movie didn't -- and def makes Dan out to be, at times, a bit of a coward, someone who had been overselling himself at work to climb the latter, but the TV series then also gives Alex backstory that is about child abuse and trauma, which is somehow perpetuated into a subplot about Dan's daughter. It becomes a story about mental illness, loss, victimization, and perceived American wealth and social standing, and about what people might do for love to make up for loss.

Comment: @DarthLocke I didn’t get what the “male” behavior Alex engaged in was? What’s the “male” behavior that Alex exhibited? I’d almost say that equating sex with love is more stereotypically feminine than masculine

Comment: The sexism in this question astounds me

Comment: @ToddWilcox Ya, I think "exhibited" is probably a better characterization. I'm not saying I agree with it necessarily, but I do think the film and the TV series are controversial in that way -- in making us think about gender "roles". That maybe it does point out double standards and male toxicity, but I also think you could remove gender from the equation all together and still ask about why Alex thought it would somehow magically work out. That argumentively, both characters seem to have different perceptions of what reality was going to be afterwards, and I think that is far question.

Comment: @DarthLocke I'm not sure if you intended to answer my question about what behavior was "male" on Alex's part. You didn't answer that question, as far as I can tell. There's nothing that strikes me as "Alex typically behaving like a man whose been having an affair with a women" (your words). "both characters seem to have different perceptions of what reality was going to be afterwards" - this has been my experience in pretty much every relationship I've ever had.

Comment: What I am saying is, there *could be subtext and/or viewer criticism here about problematic societal standards for gender roles in attempting to explain the disturbing psycho-sexual thriller's plot, where there are double standards for what is acceptable behavior vs reactions to that behavior. Well in my experience, it depends on what people have gone through vs some people thinking that they don't have to explain their expectations to others. IMO Fatal Attraction is in part cautionary tale about bad communication, but one that may be born out of victimization and the Patriarchy.

Comment: "I'm not going to be ignored, Dan."  That says it all, yeah?

Comment: @JasonPSallinger It does, but in a very vague way. It explains her intent, but it doesn't explain why it is her intent.

Comment: @JohnMeacham i am characterizing Dan the movie “Fatal attraction” as a wimp. It is odd to me that a number of people here do not or cannot separate characters in the movie with the actors playing them.  I hate what you think about actors that play murderers

Comment: @DarthLocke you hit on my point in your first response. First i would like to disclaim that i saw this when it came out and judging it by the politics at the time.   The genesis of my question is because i had hoped to see a different story.  I hoped that alex would have picked up dan for the one night stand and dumped him. A reverse gender story.  It always seemed to me the writer wimped out and delivered a safe patriarchal story.  I was wondering what others thought

Comment: @Sparkytx I’m saying that Dan not at all wimpy. The fact that Michael Douglas is also not wimpy just helps. There’s nothing Dan does that is wimpy and as I’ve mentioned, he also shows strength a few times in the story. “Wondering what others think” is not what stack exchange is for. Also you seem to be the one stereotyping women and men, not the filmmakers. You seem to assume that having a one night stand and then never calling back is something only men do.

Answer (score 4):

It’s very common in American films to treat love as a powerful overwhelming force. I assume that’s because most of us actually experience love that way.

Common philosophy of love includes the idea that we cannot choose whom we love. It’s also widely believed that when we feel a powerful love for someone, it is difficult to control our thoughts and even our actions, and we are prone to acting irrationally because of this powerful emotion and attraction that we feel.

So it is with *Fatal Attraction*. Whether anyone watching the movie believes Alex and Dan are feeling love or just lust for each other, it’s clear that Alex feels it as a strong emotion of love and attraction for Dan. So strong that she acts irrationally, with unrealistic expectations, and eventually becomes so desperate that she is violent.

It’s both believable and cathartic for many viewers because it’s quite common to feel powerful emotions that impel us to act out destructively.

In terms of choosing Dan (whom I don’t think everyone would agree is “wimpy” - Michael Douglas is widely seen as a sexy and charismatic person), “we don’t choose who we love”. It doesn’t matter whether it makes any sense to fall for Dan or not - that’s not how love works (at least in American cinema, but personally I’ve experienced this kind of attraction).

In terms of what Alex expects, it doesn’t have to be rational but if you put her to it, I’m sure she’d say that she does want Dan to leave his wife and be with Alex. This isn’t that unusual an expectation and it has been a choice that many people have made in the real world.

Comment: Thank you i can see your point. It seems she drove the entire relationship and showed more personality.. i guess dan showed her something for her to fall in love with. And all bets are offfell in love. I am totally confused by the number of comments talking about Michael Douglas not being a wimp. This seems to imply that since he is a sexy person he cannot play a wimp so he is being called a bad actor?

Comment: @Sparkytx Maybe it would help use understand why you think Dan is a "wimp". He's a successful lawyer. Dan physically overpowers Alex on multiple occasions, including when she is holding a knife and he is unarmed, so he has both the will and the strength to do so. I can't think of anything about him that is wimpy.

Comment: i am referring to the first part of the movie.  Dan says he is  married but has the one night stand anyway. He weakly tries to stop seeing alex again but can help himself.  I would say the fault for the situation falls totally on him. Have i remember it correctly?

Comment: @Sparkytx Dan's behavior in the first part of the movie is not at all what I would consider "wimpy". You and I probably have two different ideas of what it means to be a wimp. I'm not sure what most people think a wimp is, but maybe Alex sees Dan more the way I see him and she doesn't see him the way you see him.

Comment: Todd, do you find Dan’s behavior of cheating on his family acceptable or an expected alpha male behavior? I do not. May that is where we disagree. Personally, as a married man, i would have had the strength not to get told by my d**k what to do.  Dan apparently did not.  He did not have the strength to stand up to his sexual urges. Maybe wimp is a bad choice of words

Comment: @Sparkytx Seems more like an opinion based discussion topic and not a stack exchange style Q&A. Perhaps you might want to bring up your thoughts in the chat and ask others there how they see it.

Answer (score 3):

Alex doesn't know. Alex acted on impulse and I don't believe she was prepared to develope feelings for Dan. Alex wants Dan to accept her and reciprocate her strong feelings. She has a debilitating fear of rejection. Alex wants in a few days what took time for Dan's current partner to have with him. Alex wants Dan to revert back to his 20s and practice serial monogamy. She is selfish and immature and honestly she would probably faint if Dan said "OK I'm leaving her,  let's run away together".

Comment: Interesting, thank you for a thoughtful reply